# How to debug and fix the issue of system systemd (systemctl) not being able to launch the service post machine reboot?

Tags: systemd

After restarting the machine, the following command `sudo systemctl status myapi_test.service` shows:

```
myapi_test.service - This is a Test api
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myapi_test.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

I was expecting that the service should auto start after system reboot. Following is my systemctl service file.

```
[Unit]
Description=Test web application
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/my_test_api
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/my_test_api/venv/bin/python myprogram.py
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The same issue (service not starting post machine reboot) happens with other services - for example: nginx.

What is the way to debug and fix this issue?

Comment: The status of `myapi_test.service` shows that it is not `enabled`. You have to first enable it with `sudo systemctl enable myapi_test.service`, if you want it to start right now, add `--now` option.

Comment: I had enabled it immediately after creating the file. And then I had started the service. Not sure how this got reset. Is there any way (command) to check the current enable/disable status of the service?

Comment: `Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myapi_test.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)` In this line,  `disabled` between semi columns show the current state of the service. Another option would be `systemctl list-unit-files | grep -i myapi_test`. The first enabled/disabled is the current status, the second is vendor preset.